# load div inside another div at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this small code which allows the user to click in a dropdown menu and then it opens the content in a div using AJAX. The content is located in the same page, so the goal is to load that content div into another div. The problem is that when i load the content it loads the page itself (see print bellow)

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li class='active'><a href='#' data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html#qhelp" ><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href='#' data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html#qhelp"><span>Project</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='#' data-url="#homePage> *"><span>Team</span></a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='last'><a href='#' data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Main_page%20(5)#cssmenu"><span>News</span></a></li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Search</span></a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Quick Search</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Advanced Search</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Structure Search</span></a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Tools</span></a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href='#'><span>NAMS</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Smiles Calculator</span></a></li>
                <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Empty</span></a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
          <li class="active"><a class="clickableLink" href="#tab_quick" data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html#qhelp">Quick Search</a></li>
          <li><a class="clickableLink" href="#tab_advanc" data-url="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
          <li><a class="clickableLink" href="#tab_struct" data-url="something3.txt">Structure Search</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="tab_quick" class="tab-pane active"></div>
          <div id="tab_advanc" class="tab-pane active"></div>
          <div id="tab_struct" class="tab-pane active"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="all_divs">
  <div id="homePage"><p>HOME PAGE</p></div>
      <div id="biogPage"><p>BIOG PAGE</p></div>
      <div id="musicPage"><p>MUSIC PAGE</p></div>
      <div id="photosPage"><p>PHOTOS PAGE</p></div>
  </div>

  <script>$('#homePage,#biogPage, #musicPage, #photosPage, #shopPage').hide();</script>
```

**javascript**

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');

    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
      $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
      var checkElement = $(this).next();

      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }

      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }

      if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

})(jQuery);


//para abrir cada bootstrap tab com ajax
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tab_quick').load($('#tabs .active a').attr("data-url"), function(result) {
    $('.active a').tab('show');
  });

  $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash; /*vai buscar a parte do href que contem hash(#) , neste caso para o primeiro vai buscar #home*/
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url, function(result) {
      pane.tab('show');
    });

  });

});


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cssmenu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $('#tabs').load(url, function(result) { // load the content directly to #tabs     
      pane.tab('show'); // display the tab
    });
  });

});
```

**When i click for example in News at menu it loads complete page not the div. It also happens when i click About->Team**

Comment: You should always format your code with correct indention, otherwise it is hard to read.

Comment: Thank you, i am new at this.

Comment: tldr; `$('#page1').load('http://page2 #partyouwant')`

Comment: Shouldn't `data-url` be e.g: `data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html #qhelp"` See space between URI and hash

Comment: Although it is the least thing you should do when you ask a question, it is actually something that you should do for your own advantage. How do you want to be able to find problems in your code if you are not able to see its structure. Especially when you are a beginner you should take much care about proper formatting.

Comment: @A.Wolff it solved by problem for external links !! But it if want a div from the same page, for example those divs wrapped in all_divs (Bottom of html code) it loads the page itself :/. Example: if i want data-url='#homePage'

Answer (score 0):

Just changed `data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html#qhelp"` to

```
data-url="http://localhost/bioinformatica/Main_page/Quick_search.html #qhelp"
```